Salesforce CLI Deployment Warnings: GlobalValueSet returned from org but not found in local project
I'm encountering an issue when deploying using the Salesforce CLI. Although the deployment completes successfully, I receive several warnings like these:
Warning: GlobalValueSet, Value_Set_One__gvs, returned from org, but not found in the local project
Warning: GlobalValueSet, Status_Type__gvs, returned from org, but not found in the local project
Warning: GlobalValueSet, Confidentiality_Level__gvs, returned from org, but not found in the local project
...

The confusing part is that these GlobalValueSets do exist in my local project under force-app/main/default/globalValueSets/*.globalValueSet-meta.xml.
Why are these warnings showing up even though the GlobalValueSets are present locally?

Another workaround is to configure API version 56.0 in sfdx-project.json, and use that version when deploying using the --api-version commandline switch
fwiw:

the bug report in the CLI public issue tracker can be found here
the known issue at Salesforce Support can be found here


This is a behavior change introduced in Salesforce API version 57.0 and later, where Global Value Sets automatically get the __gvs suffix appended to the developer name
Refer:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm
So what I did was
renamed the GlobalValueSet
from
Value_Set_One.globalValueSet-meta.xml to Value_Set_One__gvs.globalValueSet-meta.xml
and in the body I added the full name XML element as below with the value as
Value_Set_One__gvs


     Value_Set_One__gvs
    
        one
        false
        one
    
    one
    one
    false

When I deployed the code it worked without any error but when I later did:
sf project retrieve start --metadata GlobalValueSet:Value_Set_One__gvs
Retrieving v60.0 metadata from test-asacwiej@example.com using the v62.0 SOAP API
Preparing retrieve request... Succeeded
Retrieved Source
| State   Name                   Type           Path
| ─────── ────────────────────── ────────────── ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
| Created Value_Set_One GlobalValueSet force-app/main/default/globalValueSets/Value_Set_One.globalValueSet-meta.xml
Which means the Salesforce CLI is still retrieving the Global Value Set without the __gvs suffix, even though I explicitly requested it with the __gvs suffix.
most likely a CLI bug.
A workaround could be - after you just create the scratch org. just do:
sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts
This will update the source tracking ("lastRetrievedFromServer") in .sf/orgs/org-id/maxRevision.json for the global value sets
